# Chrome Capturing Visible Tab not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

The code in **`buttonClicked()`** function and **`onTabCreate()`** function worked when the **button** is the **BrowserAction icon**.

But when I added a **popup.html** and created few buttons in it. When **`"Trello"`** button is clicked. I want the code in **`buttonClicked()`** to be executed, I put this code in **eventPage.js**.

[image]

The control is reaching the function, but *I'm unable to capture the visible Tab now*. 
**Why is it so? How can I fix this?**

As evident from the code, `imageData` is holding the image of the tab (3rd line in `buttonClicked()`)

The last 4th line in  `buttonClicked()`, calls `onTabCreate()`. In`onTabCreate()`, I'm passing the `imageData`, but I'm not receiving the image.

I'll furnish more info if needed.

Thanks

**buttonClicked()**-

```
function buttonClicked() {

    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null, {}, function (image) {
      imageData = image;

      createdTabUrl = chrome.extension.getURL('cardCreate.html');

      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true }, function (tabs) {
        var i, tab;


        // Only select the current active tab, not any background tab or dev tools
        for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i += 1) {
          // TODO: more robust way to check if current tab is a page from this extension (either when I get a static extension id or with a flag)
          if (tabs[i].url.match(/^http/) || tabs[i].url.match(/^chrome-extension.*\/cardCreate\.html$/)) {
            tab = tabs[i];
          }
        }

        chrome.tabs.create({ url: createdTabUrl, index: (tab.index || 0) + 1 }, onTabCreated);
      });
    });
  }
```

**onTabCreate()-**

```
  // TODO: more robust way to send image data to page ?
  function onTabCreated(tab) {
    setTimeout(function (){
      chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ imageData: imageData }, function(response) {
        // Callback does nothing
      });
    }, 1000);

    var views = chrome.extension.getViews();
    for (var i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
      var view = views[i];

      // If this view has the right URL and hasn't been used yet...
      if (view.location.href == createdTabUrl) {
        console.log("----------------------");
        // console.log(view);
        // console.log(view.location.href);
      }
    }

  }

    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(buttonClicked);
```

**EDIT :**

```
   window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById('loginText').addEventListener('click', login);
    document.getElementById('Trello').addEventListener('click', buttonClicked);
    //listener for ButtonClick
   // In popup.html , I included eventPage.js as well.
};
```

Comment: I may be wrong - but from memory, you can only send data from tab to tab in a serialized form - it doesn't support binary. So if you are trying to send an image, you'll need to first encode it (base64?).

Comment: How do you invoke `buttonClicked` from the popup? In any case, the probably cause is user gesture requirement - that would raise an error in the console.

Comment: I've realised that doesn't solve your problem at all - but may well be useful, so have left it.

If you remove the check for active tabs only, does that make a difference? It could be a timing issue that the new tab you've created is not initialized properly when you then do your check.

Comment: @Xan I added a listener in popup.js . I editted my question, please refer.

Comment: @Spode I'm getting the same result without that check too.